# Screen Mate на Python

Tags: python

Хотелось бы создать нечто подобное: этакого анимированного зверька с командами, который при желании мог бы что-то делать в системе. В сторону чего копать? PyQt?

Comment: Вы хотите что-то типа clippy.js?

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону SDL, а именно его обертке на python [PySDL2](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PySDL2/0.9.5)

Comment: jfs, да, только на рабочий стол :)

Comment: @TimurMusharapov посмотрите можно ли в качестве фона рабочего стола HTML страничку на вашей системе или HTML widget использовать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Прозрачное окно в PyQt:

```
class Main(QtGui.QMainWindow):
      def __init__(self):
          self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)
```

[Setting a transparent main window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14943142/setting-a-transparent-main-window)

Уже на такое окно можно выводить любую информацию или изображение и создать аналог Screen Mate.